# Javascript, tratando caracteres de escape

Tags: javascript, html

Em uma função eu recebo strings nesse modelo

```
message="'J\\xe1'"; //sendo '\xe1' = á
```

preciso transformar estas barras "\" em uma única barra '\' para obter o á do código unicode, sendo que essa string pode ser qualquer frase e as barras pode estar em qualquer lugar e aparecer em mais de um lugar.

Comment: Na verdade eu recebo essas variaveis pelo python, o meu código html é manipulado pelo python através do selenium.

Comment: Essas informações vem de um banco de dados

Comment: Sim, o selenium navega em páginas web, mas na minha aplicação ele pega dados do DB e insere nas páginas

Comment: Pois é, como disse, o problema pode estar em como pega esses dados e talvez esteja usando uma solução para resolver um problema que talvez nem precisasse existir, mas só estou comentando porque queria lhe dar uma força em contornar o problema de forma mais eficiente, mas se já resolveu assim tudo bem. até a proxima e um bom fim de tarde

Comment: Na verdade, o problema surge quando o python tem dificuldades de trabalhar diretamente com os caracteres fora da ASCII, então ao invés de trabalhar com os bytes, fui direto para o código unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se essa String é de confiar... caso seja uma String segura podias usar o `eval` assim:

```js
const message = "'J\\xe1'";
const parsed = eval(message);
console.log(parsed); // Já
```

Mas o mais seguro é usar por exemplo o `decodeURI`, identificar todos os caracteres hexadecimais e substituí-los um a um assim:

```js
const REGEX = /\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/g;
const hex2char = (str, hex) => {
  return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));
}

const message = "'J\\xe1 n\\xe3o tenho fome!'";
const unescaped = decodeURI(message.slice(1, -1));

const text = unescaped.replace(REGEX, hex2char);

console.log(text);
```

Comment: A segunda solução funcionou perfeitamente, a frase é passada do python através da biblioteca selenium, e python tem aquela dificuldade com unicode, essa foi a saída que encontrei. Valeu